# Magento "Store Code to Urls" at homepage

Tags: magento, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i have option "Store Code to Urls" turned on (admin -> system -> configuration -> web -> url options).

Problem is that if i access my homepage without store code, it works. I mean both examples works:
http://example.com/
http://example.com/code/
But first url (without store code) should redirect to url with store code. I've tried to put rewrite rules in htaccess but without success, i've tried planty of possibilities.

Magento build in rewrites rules doesnt seem to be helpfull - i've tried rewrite "/" to "code", but it result with "/code/code" url suffix.

Comment: do you have `Auto-redirect to Base URL` set to yes?

Comment: Yes, however my base url doesnt include code (its used for catalog paths, so i dont think i should change it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this behavior can be found in `Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite::rewrite`. There is no redirect for base URLs without store code.

Below is a pretty ugly solution, but it should work in your case. It will redirect to the base URL including store code as long as current store code is not found in the request URI:

app/code/local/Danslo/RedirectToStore/Model/Observer.php:

```
<?php

class Danslo_RedirectToStore_Model_Observer
{

    public function redirectToStore($observer)
    {
        $request    = $observer->getFront()->getRequest();
        $storeCode  = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
        $requestUri = $request->getRequestUri();

        if (strpos($requestUri, $storeCode) === false) {
            $targetUrl = $request->getBaseUrl() . '/' . $storeCode;
            header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
            header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
            header('Pragma: no-cache');
            header('Location: ' . $targetUrl);
            exit;
        }
    }

}
```

app/code/local/Danslo/RedirectToStore/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <events>
            <controller_front_init_before>
                <observers>
                    <redirect_to_store>
                        <class>Danslo_RedirectToStore_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>redirectToStore</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </redirect_to_store>
                </observers>
            </controller_front_init_before>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

app/etc/modules/Danslo_RedirectToStore.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Danslo_RedirectToStore>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Danslo_RedirectToStore>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: Hmm, i would rather not to use a sledgehammer to crack a nut, but its working so big thanks :)

Comment: Nice answer! I modified the code slightly to redirect CMS pages without store prefix: `$targetUrl = rtrim(Mage::getBaseUrl(), '/') . $requestUri;`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try, I'm encoutering the same problem.